# How to resolve "Something Went wrong" error in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, view

I am using Ubuntu 9.04
I just installed ruby and rails in my system and the webrick server seems to have been installed without any errors.

I created a "demo" rails app and created a controller 'say'. Then i created a view template 'hello.rhtml'

I started the server and entered http://localhost:3000/say/hello in my browser.

But the following error message comes in that page :)

[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_STZmOsvMijk/SuLVLsuCq1I/AAAAAAAABgc/5fcPYzMID2s/s800/Screenshot-We%27re%20sorry%2C%20but%20something%20went%20wrong%20%28500%29%20-%20Mozilla%20Firefox.png](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_STZmOsvMijk/SuLVLsuCq1I/AAAAAAAABgc/5fcPYzMID2s/s800/Screenshot-We%27re%20sorry%2C%20but%20something%20went%20wrong%20%28500%29%20-%20Mozilla%20Firefox.png)

What could have gone wrong. Please help me resolving this thing, I am a complete newbie to ruby and rails !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a log file in `log/development.log` that displays the complete error.
You can see what went wrong by analyzing the last request there.

Comment: im using mysql. when i create the demo project, i didnt configure my database connection althought my app just have to display a Hello world application ! Should i configure the database connection even for displaying a hello world message using a simple controller .!!

Comment: No you don't. If you don't need any database, you can, in your environment.rb file, uncomment the following : `config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]`. And you won't get that error.

Comment: Im still getting the same error.. i have uploaded the screen shot above,please help

Comment: Well the screenshot is of no use here. Updating your question with the appropriate log entry and showing what you've been updating in your configuration would be much more helpful.

Comment: Ya. it is resolved. i had to comment out the config.frameworks line in environment.rb file and restart the server. Now it works ! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This screen shot looks like you're running in production mode; if you were in development mode, it would show the error on the page as well as in the log.  Try setting the environment variable RAILS_ENV=development and restarting webrick.  As dmathieu commented, you'll probably see a database error.

Also, try avoiding webrick. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596902/mongrel-vs-webrick).

Comment: Well it depends of the error. If rails can't connect to mysql (and that was lakshmanan's proble), you'll have that error page even though you're in development mode.